# npm error installing serialport

Tags: npm

I'm trying to use node.js serialport package but it give some errors that I don't understand.

To simplify, I start form a clear directory 'test' and I create a new app:

> sudo npm init

Then I try to install serialport:

> sudo npm install serialport --save

but I've got this error:

> serialport@5.0.0 install /*********/test/node_modules/serialport
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> env: node: No such file or directory
>   npm WARN test@1.0.0 No description
>   npm WARN test@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> npm ERR! file sh
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>   npm ERR! syscall spawn
>   npm ERR! serialport@5.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
>   npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the serialport@5.0.0 install script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/myUser/.npm/_logs/2017-09-17T20_33_23_435Z-debug.log

I've tryed with other versions, clear npm cache, and other strange things, but I don't get any solution.

Versions:
OSX 10.8.5
node -v:  v8.4.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok.

I've resolved it with this order to install:

> sudo npm install serialport --unsafe-perm --build-from-source

as the serialport web page says:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport

Thanks for all!